# Редакция SQL- запроса.( JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY)

Tags: sql

Определить, сколько потратил в 2005 году каждый из членов семьи?

Поля в результирующей таблице:member_name,status, costs

[image: ERD диаграмма]

```sql
SELECT member_name, status, SUM (Payments.unit_price) AS costs FROM FamilyMembers
LEFT JOIN Payments ON FamilyMembers.member_id = Payments.family_member
WHERE Payments.date BETWEEN "2005-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" AND "2005-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
GROUP BY Payments.family_member
ORDER BY costs;
```

Этот код выдает правильный результат запроса,однако сайту не нравится подобный код,где ошибка?

[ЭТО ССЫЛКА НА САЙТ С ЗАДАНИЕМ](https://sql-academy.org/ru/trainer/tasks/17)

Comment: может вернете текст вопроса назад?

Comment: Если возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно. Не нужно полностью изменять вопрос на другой, особенно когда есть ответы на изначальную версию вопроса.

Comment: Зачем в этой задаче группировать по нескольким столбцам? GROUP BY fm.member_id, fm.member_name, fm.status Почему не срабатывает если просто по member_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сколько потратил в 2005 году каждый из членов семьи?
> Поля в результирующей таблице:member_name,status, costs

**unit_price** - цена единицы товара, её нужно умножить на количество (**amount**)

```
SELECT fm.member_name, fm.status, SUM(p.amount*p.unit_price) as costs
FROM FamilyMembers as fm
JOIN Payments as p ON p.family_member = fm.member_id
WHERE YEAR(p.date) = 2005
GROUP BY fm.member_id, fm.member_name, fm.status
```

Comment: Оо,спасибо Вам. мне просто надо было прописать это : SUM (Payments.amount * Payments.unit_price) AS costs

Comment: Да, поэтому я и описал это отдельно. Надеюсь, что остальная часть ответа тоже станет для вас полезной.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант решения этого задания с сайта.

```
WITH report AS (
    SELECT  member_name, 
            status, 
            good_name, 
            SUM(amount*unit_price) AS costs 
    FROM FamilyMembers JOIN Payments
    ON member_id = family_member
    JOIN Goods ON good_id = good
    WHERE member_name LIKE "%Quincey" 
    AND date LIKE "2005-07%" 
    OR date LIKE "2005-08%"
    OR date LIKE "2005-09%"
    GROUP BY member_name, status, good_name
    ORDER  BY member_name, costs DESC
)
SELECT * FROM report 
UNION 
SELECT NULL, NULL, "Total:", SUM(costs) FROM report
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]